# Chown doesn't work on my web server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, chmod, fs, chown

I get an issue using `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` on my web server (ubuntu 14.04).

My NodeJS application is using the `fs` module and when I want to edit a `json` file it works only if I do a `sudo chmod 0777 myfile`, with the `chown` it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Node app running as user `www-data`?

Comment: I don't know I'm using `pm2` to run NodeJS. `pm2 start ./bin/www --name myapp`...

Answer (score 0):

The chown command made the user `www-data` the owner of the files in `/var/www`, which means that to get full (r/w) access to those files you either have to run your Node app as that user as well (`sudo -u www-data 'pm2 start ...'`), you have to adjust the permissions on the file(s) so that your regular user id can write them (like you found out after chmodding them to 0777), or you have to chown the files to your regular user id (but there's probably a reason why you chowned them to `www-data` in the first place).

I would opt for the first solution (using `su`).

Comment: I do `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` for security reasons... Ok and Is that works if I do `www-data pm2 start...` without `su`?

Comment: @tonymx227 no, you need `su` to be able to start a process as a particular user (`www-data` in this case)

Comment: I get an issue using this command `su: unrecognized option '--name'`

Comment: Ok that's better but now "Authentication failure", I don't know the password of `www-data`... I just know the root password !

Comment: @tonymx227 in that case you can use `sudo` instead. See edit.

Comment: Issue : `sudo: pm2 start ./bin/www --name myapp: command not found`